# Selenium-webdriver count tables array

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver and i need to count all table elements for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainholder"]/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form[3]/table[4]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainholder"]/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form[3]/table[5]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainholder"]/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form[3]/table[6]')
```

This will return 3 for my counter but if i have more then these 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.find_elements_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath):

```
tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainholder"]/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/form[3]/table')
print(len(tables))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mytables = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table")
```

This might do the job.